# Facebook integration email value not showing in json response

Tags: android, facebook

Here is my `JSONObject` get from Facebook.

```
{
    "id": "673712949465129",
    "name": "Shyam SelvaKumar",
    "link": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/673712949465129\/",
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "is_silhouette": false,
            "url": "https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-1\/p50x50\/13567404_583364415166650_2716003405410548102_n.jpg?oh=16aa11f12003863ac931a9ec744f3b43&oe=58DF0121"
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting the email value in response.

Comment: Are you asking for the email field? Have the user given your app email permission? Does the user have a verified email address?

Answer (score 0):

Try with other user profile. 
because Facebook will provide you a user's email id if and only that user has a confirmed email id associated with his account.

Comment: User have a verified email address or not? and try with Test User.

Answer (score 0):

Your Facebook `Graph request` Should look like this:

```
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("FACEBOOK LOGIN", response.toString());
                            // Application code
                            try {
                                String fb_id = object.getString("id");
                                String fb_name = object.getString("name");
                                String profilePicUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?width=200&height=200";
                                String fb_gender = object.getString("gender");
                                String fb_email = object.getString("email");
                                String fb_birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(small)");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString())
        }
```

Also you need to `setReadpermission` in your Facebook `loginButtton`

```
 loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
                "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
```

Also another thing `Facebook Sdk` won't return your email id if it's privacy is not  public